# Not sure if SQL Server 2008 Express was upgrade to Web Edition

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 Express Edition and I needed to upgraded to either Express Edition R2 or R2 Web edition.

So I ran the set up of R2 Web and go to the maintenance and select Edition Upgrade. Then I went thru the Wizard and inserted the key and Set up said the upgrade has completed.

But when I check in the Management Studio, it still shows as SQL Server 10.0.400.

So did it actually upgraded to R2 Web?

Answer (score 4):

You're just looking at the version number, which does not change via an edition upgrade.

In SQL Server Management Studio, the key you're looking for is "Product"

[image]

Comment: Mine still shows as Express Edition

Comment: @YeMyatAung - in that case, the answer to your question `So did it actually upgraded to R2 Web?` is "no"

Comment: You might find the following question useful: http://serverfault.com/questions/304610/best-way-to-upgrade-sql-server-express-to-web-edition - it turns out you *cannot* upgrade any edition to Web in-place.

Comment: Ok. Another question is, can I install a separate Web edition and attach database later?

Comment: @YeMyatAung - yes. You can install multiple copies of SQL Server side by side on Named Instances, and then move the database and update your connection strings.